# Why there is no apostrophe in Screen Writers Guild?

Tags: plot-explanation, mank

In *Mank* (2020), Joe and Hermie are sitting in a corner of a resturant.
They both discuss about the Screen Writers Guild:

> Joe: Hermie, the guild's in its infancy. It needs you.
>
> Hermie: You're telling me. **What writer failed to notice the Screen
> Writers Guild needs an apostrophe?** As Groucho always said, "Never
> belong to any club that would have someone like you for a member."

Why there is no apostrophe in Screen Writers Guild?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the English language, and not about movies and/or TV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really this isn't a question about a movie but about English and might be best asked on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) or [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)

However it comes down to a subtle difference - whether the noun "screen writers" is descriptive or possessive.  Is it:

- a guild populated by screen writers (descriptive) or
- a guild owned by screen writers (possessive)?

Arguably it is closer to descriptive than possessive. It's more important that it is a "guild comprising screen writers as members" rather than they are merely the owners.  Really "screen writers" is acting as an adjective, describing the guild.  It is a "guild of screen writers" not simply a "guild owned by screen writers".

Since it is not possessive, there is no apostrophe.

Other examples:

- visitors book
- farmers market

Comment: I am sure this was something the members were very cognizant of.